# GAMS: Filename cannot be used as valid UEL

Tags: replace, merge, filenames, gams-math

I trying to merge a large data set in gams. The file should consist of multiple gdx files with several names. The programme merges the files as I would like them to however: it replaces the names of the file to be merged with File_1, File_2, File_3 and so on. I would like to see the name of the gdx file in the merged file (and so far the script I wrote worked fine).

I'm receiving the following error for each line:

```
   ***Filename cannot be used as a valid UEL
   Existing name: ImpactYesPGTNoLDViolation-D1-PG10-LDI-LDE0.001-LB0.0045-PDC0-D10 
    Replaced with File_1
```

Why does this happen? Could it be that the existing name is too long? I tried finding out more about this error but so far have not found any information on it. And is there anyway to fix it? I need the information of the existing name in order to further process the output.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. This name is too long to be used as UEL (aka label). You can only use up to 63 characters. You can read more about this and other limitations for UELs [here](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GAMSPrograms.html#UG_GAMSPrograms_Labels)